# Botões input e botões <a> class não funcionam

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou utilizando um plugin de uma janela modal para fazer um carrinho de compras simplificado para o cliente, só que os botões de selecionar o pagseguro ou paypal como forma de de pagamento não funcionam de jeito de nenhum. Se eu clico no botão ele não redireciona para nenhuma página.

Link no codepen com os códigos: https://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/PjwoOd/ e o resultado na página: https://codepen.io/flashpremium/live/e613565ea5ed20101bdcf43dca22266b

Identifiquei que a seguinte linha de código javascript abaixo está fazendo com que os botões dentro da modal window não funcionem. O que eu faço para corrigir?

```
 self.$target.on('click', function(e) { self.hide(e) });
      self.$el.on('click', function(e) { self.show(e) }); 
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o que esteja impedindo os seus botões de funcionar, na verdade, seja os `e.preventDefault();`.

Eu iria sugerir, já que a funcionalidade dos botões está "desativada", que você devolvesse a funcionalidade para eles usando jQuery:

```
$(".btn-checkout-pagseguro").click(function() {
    $("#checkOutPag").submit();
});
```

Dando um `id` para o `form`:

```
<form target="pagseguro" action="https://example.com/"
  method="post" id="checkOutPag"> <!-- adicionando esse id -->
```

> Mas apenas comentando os `e.preventDefault();` fará sua Modal funcionar - tem alguma outra funcionalidade nela que exige o bloqueio dos eventos padrão?

```js
(function($) {
 $.modal = function(el, options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.$el = $(el);
  this.$target = $(el.hash || this.$el.attr('data-target'));
  this.$backdrop = $('.modal-backdrop');

  if (this.$target.length) {
   this.$el.data("modal", this);
   this.init();
  }
 };

 $.modal.prototype = {
  init : function() {
   var self = this, settings, backdrop = $('<div/>').addClass(
     'modal-backdrop fade');

   if (!self.$backdrop.length) {
    self.$backdrop = backdrop.appendTo('body');
   }

   self.settings = settings = $
     .extend({}, self.defaults, self.options);

   self.$target.on('click', function(e) {
    self.hide(e)
   });
   self.$el.on('click', function(e) {
    self.show(e)
   });
  },

  toggle : function(e) {
   return (this.$target.hasClass('in')) ? this.hide(e) : this.show(e);
  },

  show : function(e) {
   // e.preventDefault();
   // e.stopPropagation();
   this.$target.addClass('in');
   this.$backdrop.addClass('in');
   $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  },

  hide : function(e) {
   // e.preventDefault();
   // e.stopPropagation();

   var className = e.target.className;

   if (className == 'modal-dialog' || className == 'close') {
    this.$target.removeClass('in');
    this.$backdrop.removeClass('in');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
   }
  },

  defaults : {}
 };

 $.fn.modal = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
   new $.modal(this, options);
  });
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=modal]').modal();
 });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

button.close {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1040;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: table;
}
.modal.in {
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.8) translateZ(0);
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1050;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  background-clip: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 450px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: #000000;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-header {
  min-height: 16.428571429px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
}

.modal-body {
  height: 600px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.md-content {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.md-content h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.md-content > div {
  height: 600px;
  padding: 15px 40px 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: -120px;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.md-content > div p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 250px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.entrega {
  width: 47%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: left;
}

.about {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.70;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #313c41;
  background: #d7e3ea;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.md-content > div ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 30px 20px;
}
.md-content > div ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.md-content button {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.md-effect-1 .md-content {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
  transform: scale(0.7);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-show.md-effect-1 .md-content {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.md-effect-2 .md-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(20%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(20%);
  transform: translateX(20%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
}

.md-show.md-effect-2 .md-content {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 32em) {
  body {
    font-size: 75%;
  }
}


.btn-checkout-pagseguro {
  background: #2cf46d;
  border: 2px solid #2cf46d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 200ms;
}

.btn-checkout-pagseguro:hover {
border: 2px solid #fff;
font-size: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #2cf46d;   /*#8be309;*/
}

.btn-checkout-pagseguro:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
   transform: scale(0.95);

}

.btn-checkout {
  background: #0b74c9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #0b74c9;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-checkout:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0b74c9;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn-checkout:active {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
   transform: scale(0.95);
}

input#tab-one, input#tab-two, input#tab-three {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.tab-content .tab-one-content, .tab-content .tab-two-content, .tab-content .tab-three-content {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  opacity: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}

input#tab-one:checked ~ .tab-content .tab-one-content, input#tab-two:checked ~ .tab-content .tab-two-content, input#tab-three:checked ~ .tab-content .tab-three-content {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

input#tab-one:checked ~ .tabs label[for="tab-one"], input#tab-two:checked ~ .tabs label[for="tab-two"], input#tab-three:checked ~ .tabs label[for="tab-three"] {
  background: #b8c2c8;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: 350ms;
          transition: 350ms;
}

.tabs-holder {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: transparent;
}

.tabs > label {
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #0070cb;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f6f9fb;
  font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.tabs > label:hover{
  background:#d1d0ed;
}

[for] ~ [for] {
  border-left: 0;
}

.tabs > label:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.tab-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 11px;
  clear: both;
  border-top: 0;
}

.nome-produto {
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #0070cb;
  border: 1px solid #0070cb;
  font-family: roboto;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
   <div class="cell">
      <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Abrir Modal</a>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <div class='md-content google'>
               <p>
               <div>
                  <div class="tabs-holder">
                     <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="tab-one" checked="">
                     <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="tab-two">
                     <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="tab-three">
                     <div class="tabs">
                        <label for="tab-one" style="border-radius: 30px 0px 0px 30px;">PagSeguro</label>
                        <label for="tab-two" style="border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 0px;">PayPal</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-one-content">
                           <br>
                           <!-- PagSeguro -->
                           <form target="pagseguro" action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/v2/cart.html?action=add" method="post" id="test">
                              <input type="submit" value="Pague com PagSeguro" class="btn-checkout-pagseguro" src="">
                           </form>
                           <!-- ./PagSeguro -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-two-content">
                           <br>
                           <!-- New PayPal Update -->
                           <form method="post" action="py/processando.php" target="_blank">
                              <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="Conta Premium Minecraft Original"> 
                              <input type="hidden" name="itemnumber" value="10000"> 
                              <input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="Minecraft Original"> 
                              <input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="29.90">
                              <input class="btn-checkout" value="Pagar com PayPal" type="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/BR/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - A maneira fácil e segura de enviar pagamentos online!">
                              <!-- ./New PayPal Update -->
                           </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-three-content">
                           Tab Three Content
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Resolveu o problema! Obrigado Daniel Gomes.